# RecyclerView.Adapter notifyDataSetChanged() not working when is showing last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged, gridlayoutmanager

I'm implementing an endless data loading for a `RecyclerView`. When software detects the last item is going to be shown, it downloads new items and call to the following function (running it in the main thread):

```
int visibleItemCount = numberOfItemsPerRow;
int pastVisiblesItems = ((GridLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
if (loading) {
    if ((visibleItemCount+pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
    .
    .
    .

    //After downloading data

    loading = false;
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public  void  run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

However, if I scroll quickly and the last item is shown before receiving new data, `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work. Only if I scroll up and down again, to force the render of the new data, these new data is shown.

Any idea about what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try**:

```
        RecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {  
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
```

**Edit:**

For you to use it to determine the right position you use,
I bet your position does not reflect the appropriate condition:

- When the view is empty, last visible position will be -1
- When the view got one element, position will be 0
- Adapter count will be 1

**Edit 2:**

I got similar approach:

- Searching Thread which holds data in Queue
- On demand, the queue is emptied
- I got adapter

  `public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemCardAdapter.ViewHolder>`
- In the adapter I got a list:

  `List<T> _itemList;`

  - I got methods `add(item)`/`addAll(collection)`/`clear()` to manage item list
  - Three Overridden methods:

    `@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      return _itemList.size();
    }`

    `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) { }`

    `@Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {}`
- And holder:

  `public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {}`
- I'm managing data via `Adapter.add();`,  `clear();` and then I call `Adapter.notifidatasetChanged();` as Runnable on UI Thread  I have no issue like you

Which libraries do you use?

Mine are:

- appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
- support-v4:22.2.0'
- design:22.2.0'
- recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
- cardview-v7:22.2.0'

Comment: What is this? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm already handling the scroll listener. Code above is part of the routine that is done in the method onScrolled. I detect correctly when new data must be downloaded. My problem is in the notifyDataSetChanged(), that sometimes fails (when last item is in the view).